# Hokuyo UST-10LX connected via Ethernet and urg_node

Tags: ros2, wifi, turtlebot, urg-node, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

**TL;DR**

When I don't use `urg_node` with Hokuyo UST-10LX, I can see ROS2 topics from the robot on the other PC, after using `urg_node` with the Hokuyo laser scanner - `ros2 topic list` doesn't have them, `ssh` doesn't work either, I don't know why?

My configuration:

- ROS 2 Galactic, Ubuntu 20.04 on each PC and an Intel NUC on the TurtleBot 2
- Everything is on the local network with addresses in 192.168.5.xxx, i.e. TB2 IP is `192.168.5.55`, the PC IP is `192.168.5.100` etc. Gateway's IP: `192.168.5.1`.
- TB2 has Hokuyo UST-20LX connected via Ethernet cable to Intel NUC, NUC has a WiFi internet access; default IP of the Hokuyo sensor is `192.168.0.10` (important later).

To see other ROS topics on the local network on my PC, that are published by nodes running on TB2 or other computer, I need to add this route on the PC and similar on the TB2:

`sudo route add -net 192.168.5.0 gw 192.168.5.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev wlp7s0`

I was able to use `ros2 run demo_nodes_py talker` on the PC and see it on the TB2 (`ros2 run demo_nodes_py listener`), same with analogous situation - talker on the TB2 and listener on the PC. It seems that everything works as expected.

Everything broke down when I added the Hokuyo connected via Ethernet cable - I couldn't see (`ros2 topic list`) any other topics or send/listen to any messages.

When I tried to change Hokuyo's IP from the default 192.168.0.10 to the 192.168.5.65 and restarted the whole robot and it's NUC, it seemingly broke the Internet connection - I couldn't `ssh` to the TB2 or see the robot's ROS topics in the network on the PC.

I found some other questions which seems to be related to this problem, but I can't find a solution:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/297291/error-connecting-to-hokuyo-could-not-open-network-hokuyo/
- https://github.com/ros-drivers/urg_node/issues/79
- https://www.finnrietz.dev/linux/hokuyo-ros-setup/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/211508/etcnetworkinterfaces-configuration-for-urg-node/

How can I use the TB2 with Hokuyo LiDAR connected via Ethernet, with TB2 accessing the Internet via WiFi (so I could `ssh` to it) and with ROS2 DDS working as it should (e.g. topics from TB2 are visible from another PC on the same network)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404039/hokuyo-ust-10lx-connected-via-ethernet-and-urg_node/) by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3064 on 2022-07-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [igrak34](https://answers.ros.org/users/109560/igrak34/) on 2022-07-22**:
I encountered same problem, so if someone knows how to fix it please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With help of my friend I get it to work, I will try to describe changes with steps:

- I don't need to use any `route add` - I deleted every added route with `sudo route del ...`
- Wired connection on the TB2 with Hokuyo LiDAR - settings: IP `192.168.0.15` with netmask `255.255.255.0` without gateway
- For the working DDS I had to use this [setup guide](https://dds-demonstrators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Teams/1.Hurricane/setupCycloneDDS.html), with preparation of XML settings file called `cyclonedds.xml` (I changed `wifi0` to `wlp58s0`, check it with `ifconfig` for your case):

  > ```
  > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
  > <CycloneDDS xmlns="https://cdds.io/config"
  > xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  > xsi:schemaLocation="https://cdds.io/config
  > https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/master/etc/cyclonedds.xsd">
  >     <Domain id="any">
  >         <General>
  >             <NetworkInterfaceAddress>wifi0</NetworkInterfaceAddress>
  >         </General>
  >     </Domain>  
  > </CycloneDDS>
  > ```

(XML isn't showing nice in this editor, so there is the picture too)

[image: image description]

and then put `export CYCLONEDDS_URI=file://$PWD/cyclonedds.xml` in the `~/.bashrc`

I could then launch my nodes on the TB2 with plugged-in Hokuyo, with ROS2 topics visible on the other PC.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1